# Is it good to roll your lower back with tennis ball?

Tags: lower-back, foam-rolling

As can be seen in the following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePDIhxIf2CI) it is forbidden to practice with foam roller in the lower back. But is the situation is different with tennis ball?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's "forbidden" to foam roll your lower back is because you don't have a rib cage there to protect your internal organs.

You *can*, and often *should* foam roll your lower back, but it should be done with something larger than a foam roller to spread out the pressure over a larger area.

So no, do NOT use a tennis ball to roll the lumbar region of your back.

If you feel like you have a reason to do so, go get a proper massage. I would highly advise that everyone does this anyway.

Comment: The rib cage actually provides structural support for your spine in addition to your organs. Foam rolling your lower back puts the lumbar spine into hyper extension because of this lack of support. Your organs will move out of the way but you put your lumbar spine at risk when foam rolling.